# How can my program know when the server is done processing my request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I am connecting to my mail server using IMAP and Telnet.  Once I am connected I am marking all items in the inbox as read.  Some times the inbox will only have a couple of e-mails, sometimes the inbox may have thousands of e-mails.  I am storing the response from the server into a Byte array, but the Byte array has a fixed length.

```
Private client As New TcpClient("owa.company.com", 143)
Private data As [Byte]()
Private stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
.
. some code here generates a response that I want to read
.
data = New [Byte](1024) {}
bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
```

But the response from the server varies based on how many e-mails are successfully marked as read since I get one line of confirmation for each e-mail processed.  There are times where the response may contain only 10-20 lines, other times it will contain thousands of lines.  Is there any way for me to be able to get the response from the server in its entirety?  I mean it seems like I would have to know when the server was done processing my request, but I'm not sure how to go about accomplishing this.

So to reiterate my question is:  How can I check in my program to see when the server is done processing a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the NetworkStream's DataAvailable property:

```
if( stream.CanRead)
{
  do{
     bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
     //append the data read to wherever you want to hold it.
     someCollectionHoldingTheFullResponse.Add( data);
  } while( stream.DataAvailable);
}
```

At the end, "someCollectionHoldingTheFullResponse" (memory stream? string? List<byte>? up to your requirements) would hold the full response.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check the unread mail count? If there are no unread mail, then all have been marked as unread :)

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server) has an interesting example of C# code communicating over TCP to a server. It shows how to use a While loop to wait until the server has sent over all data over the wire.

Concentrate on the HandleClientComm() routine, since this some code you may wish to use.